# POSTing JSON to Spring MVC Controller Returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'd like to POST JSON and have Jackson convert it to a POJO, but for now I can't even POST a simple String parameter.

1. I'm using Jackson 2.3.2 (jackson-core and jackson-databaind)
2. I'm using Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE (spring-context, spring-webmvc)
3. My Controller looks like this:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="add-name", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
   public String addName(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
       LOG.info(String.format("name: %s", name));
       return "name";
   }
   ```
4. I POST to this Controller with data like this:

   ```
   { "name" : "my_name" }
   ```
5. The response I receive is `400 Bad Request`

Note: I'm submitting the POST via [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), but to remove that as a variable, I'm also submitting POST via [FF Poster add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) specifying the URL, Content Type (application/json), and data as above.

**Edit:** I think the issue may be that the Jackson library isn't even being called. I took it out of the dependencies and nothing changes, no different error/exception, I still simply get a `400 Bad Request` response.

**Edit 2:** Even if I take out the parameter to `addName` completely and post an empty body `{}` I still get a `400 Bad Request`

Comment: Why are you using JSON with POST instead of the standard form encoding? jQuery will transform your request into form encoding for you client-side with no trouble.

Comment: I was getting a 400 BAD Request response that way as well

Comment: Try using `consumes` instead of a manual header specification, and use the Spring `MediaType` constant for JSON. Probably not the issue, but it will eliminate one more Thing That Can Go Wrong.

Comment: Good advice, but it doesn't the change result, so doesn't appear to be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downgraded to Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE and Jackson 1.9.9 and it works now. Seems like a hack. I thought Spring 3.2 and Jackson 2 were compatible.

Comment: Spring 3.2 uses MappingJackson2MessageConverter, did you register this bean in your app?

Answer (score 3):

You are posting raw data in the body, but your controller is looking for a parameter named `name`. Either post with a parameter `name` whose value is `my_name`, or use `@RequestBody` in the handler to pass in the JSON object.

Comment: If I create an object `Name` with a name field, change the parameter to `@RequestBody Name name`, and POST the same data, I still get a `400 Bad Request`