# Spring @RequestBody causes HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed when mapping POJO

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've been building a RESTful API using Spring recently and I'm stuck at the point of mapping request bodies into POJOs.

To be clear, I have probably read 50 other StackOverflow questions stating similar symptoms but to no avail.

Using the `@RequestBody` annotation, my controller can successfully map the request body to a `String`. When using POJOs however, Spring complains that `o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported`.

Controller:

```
package api.controller;

import api.domain.SimplePOJO;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Slf4j
@RestController
public class TestController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public SimplePOJO testing(@RequestBody SimplePOJO simplePOJO) {
    log.info("Made it into the testing method.");
    return simplePOJO;
  }
}
```

SimplePOJO:

```
package api.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SimplePOJO {
  private String name;

  private Integer age;
}
```

My application configuration is not all that complicated, either. Perhaps it is missing something?

```
package api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

I may also be missing something from my application dependencies, so my pom.xml is attached:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>api</groupId>
    <artifactId>API</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
            <version>r03</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I cannot POST data of any content type and have it succeed. I have tried the forms JSON, form-data, and x-www-form-urlencoded. All lead to the 405 Method Not Allowed error. If needed, I can post the request details here. I am using Postman for testing so I am fairly certain that the request is well formed.

When I start the application, I see `s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public api.domain.SimplePOJO api.controller.TestController.testing(api.domain.SimplePOJO)` in the console.

Comment: Use firebug to analyze the data to make sure it matches up with the object

Comment: @KevinBowersox, the request appears to be properly formed: http://i.imgur.com/xwgugMK.png

Comment: Can you post the code that you do the ´post´ (javascript or whatever)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I am not interfacing with the API using Javascript. The equivalent curl request to the Postman request would be: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ name: "Mr User", age: 22 }' http://localhost:8080/test`

Comment: Try to add `, headers={"Content-Type=application/json"}` to your `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)` on your TestController

Comment: @JorgeCampos My @RequestMapping now reads `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers={"Content-Type=application/json"})` and I'm still getting the error. I also re-tried using `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'name=Mr+User&age=22' http://localhost:8080/test` which also continues to get the error.

Comment: Post the request details. What client are you using? Postman?

Comment: @shazin Yes, I'm using Postman. A typical request looks like the one I commented earlier in reply to Kevin: http://i.imgur.com/xwgugMK.png

Comment: Follow my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687513/posting-json-to-controller-returns-400-bad-request/27689195#27689195

Comment: @shazin As you can see, the request details are generated by exactly the same method you describe in your answer. The header values in the previous image indicate that the request is specifying a body type of JSON as you describe. http://i.imgur.com/5CXm9IQ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the request.

```
{ "name":"shazin", "age":28 }
```

Comment: That's it. I knew it was going to be something silly like this. Thank you! Note to self: do not validate JSON in a Javascript interpreter.